# PHP imap_search not detecting all messages in gmail inbox

Tags: php, gmail, imap

When I run a very simple `imap_search` on my GMail inbox, the search returns less messages than it should.

Here is the script that anyone with a GMail account can run.

```
$host = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}';
$user = 'foo';
$pass = 'bar';

$imapStream = imap_open($host,$user,$pass) or die(imap_last_error());

$messages = imap_search($imapStream,"ALL");

echo count($messages);

imap_close($imapStream);
```

This returns 39 messages.  But, I've got 100 messages in my inbox, some bundled in conversations, some forwarded from another account (SquirrelMail).

Can anyone duplicate these results, and/or tell me what's going on?

---

Other server strings I've tried, all returning the same results:

```
{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}
{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX
{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX
```

GMail's IMAP feature support: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78761

Comment: Tried `imap_sort`, `imap_num_msg`, and `imap_search`, same results.

Comment: Tried "Advanced IMAP Controls" in Google Labs, same results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After significant hair loss, I've found the answer.  It was a misleading UI.

GMail groups one's messages into "Conversations" by default.  These conversations can include archived messages.

So, for example, Bob's inbox *looks like* there's 4 conversations of 25 messages, which should apparently return 100 inbox messages.  In reality, 60 of the messages are in the archive (not the inbox), so the `imap_search()` returns `40`.  These messages are magically pulled out of the archive and placed into inbox conversations.

In the *Settings->General* menu, you can toggle conversation view, which will put all of those naughty archived messages back where they belong, and show your true inbox view.

Comment: `After significant hair loss` LOL ... same here

Answer (score 0):

imap_search criteria ALL - return all messages matching the rest of the criteria , so i ask you where is the rest of the criteria ?

You could use `imap_sort($imapStream, 'SORTDATE', 0);` ( imap_sort - Gets and sorts message numbers by the given parameters [imap_sort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-sort.php) ) .

---

Edit , here is some code that goes thru all messages in you're inbox , instead of imap_num_msg , you could use imap_sort as stated before , so you get you're inbox sorted if you like .

```
<?php
    $imap = imap_open("{mail.yourserver.com:143}INBOX", "username", "password");
    $message_count = imap_num_msg($imap);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $message_count; ++$i) {
        $header = imap_header($imap, $i);
        $body = trim(substr(imap_body($imap, $i), 0, 100));
        $prettydate = date("jS F Y", $header->udate);

        if (isset($header->from[0]->personal)) {
            $personal = $header->from[0]->personal;
        } else {
            $personal = $header->from[0]->mailbox;
        }

        $email = "$personal <{$header->from[0]->mailbox}@{$header->from[0]->host}>";
        echo "On $prettydate, $email said \"$body\".\n";
    }

    imap_close($imap);
?>
```

Comment: @poelinca - "ALL" is the criterion, I want all of the messages in the inbox.  I tried `imap_sort` just now, and it returned the same results.  :/

Comment: please see my update answer , looking at php.net ALL shouldn't be used alone , that would mean you can use ANY as a standalone criteria witch whont work would it ?

Comment: @poelinca - `ALL` by itself returns the same results as when I split it up with criteria. Do you have a source when you say "shouldn't be used alone"?  Also, ANY won't work because isn't in the list of criteria.

Comment: if you just whant to display the number of messages you can use imap_sort or imap_num_msg . ( i still don't think ALL should work as a standalone criteria , since you allready having problems getting all emails )

Comment: @poelinca - I understand what you're saying, but I don't know any other way to return "all inbox messages".

Comment: @poelinca -  I tried `imap_sort`, `imap_num_msg`, and `imap_search`, which all return 39. :|  Thanks for the tips though.

Comment: for me both imap_search and imap_sort return the correct number